# How to use DateTimePicker control for datetime field in Orchard editor (without adding datetimefieldpart)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editor, orchardcms, datetimepicker

I know there is DateTime field builtin Orchard and i know i can use it by adding DataTimeFieldPart to the my custom part.
But my datetime fields belongs to an "event part record" entity and i want them stored in one table.
The problem i faced is the editor view for custom part - my datetime property renders as a text input but i expect it renders like jquery timepicker or input with datetime type at least.

Is it neccesary to add all datetime properties like a separate DateTime parts?
As i see, the only way i can use datetime picker it's manually add it to the editors view. For me it's strange because Orchard provides datetime picker functionality in datetime part.

I think i'm missing some idealogic conserns.

```
        //Event Type
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("EventPartRecord",
            table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column<string>("Name")
                .Column<DateTime>("StartDateTime")
                .Column<DateTime>("PlanedEndDateTime", c=>c.Nullable())
                .Column<DateTime>("EndDateTime", c => c.Nullable())
                .Column<string>("EventRules")
                .Column<string>("Comment")
                .Column<bool>("IsFinished")
                .Column<int>("CompetitionPartRecord_Id")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("EventPart",
            builder => builder.Attachable()
                .WithField("Competitors",f => f
                .OfType("ContentPickerField")
                .WithSetting("Multiple","true"))
                );
```

Here is my editors view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlanedEndDateTime)
    </div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PlanedEndDateTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlanedEndDateTime)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary or even possible to add all datetime properties as parts: only one part of a given type can exist on a type. You could do it through fields however.

What you need to do in order to reproduce the UI of the date field in your own part is to reproduce the template and script that they use, in your own part templates.

Answer (score 0):

Using Orchard`s DateTime editor is actually possible (my Orchard version is 1.10.1) but it requires a lot of custom code. Here we go.

1. **EventPartRecord** class

   ```
   public class EventPartRecord : Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentPartRecord
   {
     // DateTime value as UTC to use Orchard convention (see CommonPart table) and to be compatible with projections
     // (date/time tokens work with UTC values, see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6963 for a related issue)  
     public virtual System.DateTime? StartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

     ...
   }
   ```
2. **EventPart** class

   ```
   public class EventPart : Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart<EventPartRecord>
   {
     // public
       public System.DateTime? StartDateTimeUtc 
       { 
         get { return Retrieve(r => r.StartDateTimeUtc); }
         set { Store(r => r.StartDateTimeUtc, value); }
       }

       public System.DateTime StartDateTime
       { 
         get
         {
           var v = ValidFromUtc;

           if (v.HasValue)
             return DateLocalizationServices.ConvertToSiteTimeZone(v.Value);
           else
             return null;
         }
       }

       // This property is needed to render Orchard`s date time editor correctly
       [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Display(Name="Start date time")]
       public Orchard.Core.Common.ViewModels.DateTimeEditor StartDateTimeProxy
       { 
         get
         {
           var v = StartDateTime;
           var lDateLocalizationOptions = new Orchard.Localization.Models.DateLocalizationOptions {EnableCalendarConversion = false, EnableTimeZoneConversion = false};

           return new Orchard.Core.Common.ViewModels.DateTimeEditor {ShowDate = true, ShowTime = true,
             Date = v.HasValue ? DateLocalizationServices.ConvertToLocalizedDateString(v.Value, lDateLocalizationOptions) : "",
             Time = v.HasValue ? DateLocalizationServices.ConvertToLocalizedTimeString(v.Value, lDateLocalizationOptions) : ""};
         }

         set
         {
           ValidFromUtc = CreateActualPropertyValue(value, "ValidFromProxy");
         }
       }

       ...

       public Orchard.Localization.Localizer T { get; set; }
       public Orchard.ContentManagement.IUpdateModel Updater { get; set; }
       public Orchard.Localization.Services.IDateLocalizationServices DateLocalizationServices { get; set; }

     // private
       private System.DateTime? CreateActualPropertyValue(Orchard.Core.Common.ViewModels.DateTimeEditor aProxyPropertyValue, string aProxyPropertyName)
       { 
         System.DateTime? v = null;

         // the following date/time handling is based on Orchard.Fields.Drivers.DateTimeFieldDriver
         bool lHasDate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(aProxyPropertyValue.Date);
         bool lHasTime = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(aProxyPropertyValue.Time);
         var lPropertyName = T(this.GetPropertyAttribute<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute>(aProxyPropertyName).Name);

         if (lHasDate && lHasTime)
         {
           try
           {
             v = DateLocalizationServices.ConvertFromLocalizedString(aProxyPropertyValue.Date, aProxyPropertyValue.Time, 
               new Orchard.Localization.Models.DateLocalizationOptions {EnableTimeZoneConversion = true});
           }
           catch
           {
             Updater.AddModelError(PartDefinition.Name + "." + aProxyPropertyName, T("{0} could not be parsed as a valid date and time.", lPropertyName));
           }
         }
         else
         {
           if (!lHasDate && lHasTime)
             Updater.AddModelError(PartDefinition.Name + "." + aProxyPropertyName, T("{0} requires a date.", lPropertyName));
           else
           if (lHasDate && !lHasTime)
             Updater.AddModelError(PartDefinition.Name + "." + aProxyPropertyName, T("{0} requires a time.", lPropertyName));
           else
           {
             // consider both fields empty as "no date time selection",
             // if property should be required add [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required] to actual property as strangely adding it to proxy property does not work
           }
         }

         return v;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **EventPartDriver** class

   ```
   public class EventPartDriver : Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver<EventPart>
   {
     // public
       public ValidityPartDriver(Orchard.Localization.Services.IDateLocalizationServices aDateLocalizationServices)
       {
         T = Orchard.Localization.NullLocalizer.Instance;

         mDateLocalizationServices = aDateLocalizationServices;
       }

       public Orchard.Localization.Localizer T { get; set; }

     // protected
       // GET
       protected override Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.DriverResult Editor(EventPart aPart, dynamic aShapeHelper)
       {
         // first, set properties which are required by the code that returns part property values for the view
         aPart.DateLocalizationServices = mDateLocalizationServices;

         return ContentShape("Parts_Event_Edit", () => aShapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Event", Model: aPart, Prefix: Prefix));
       }

       // POST
       protected override Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.DriverResult Editor(EventPart aPart,
         Orchard.ContentManagement.IUpdateModel aUpdater, dynamic aShapeHelper)
       {
         // first, set properties which are required by the code that handles part property updates executed by aUpdater.TryUpdateModel()
         aPart.T = T;
         aPart.Updater = aUpdater;
         aPart.DateLocalizationServices = mDateLocalizationServices;

         aUpdater.TryUpdateModel(aPart, Prefix, null, null);

         return Editor(aPart, aShapeHelper);
       }

     // private
       private Orchard.Localization.Services.IDateLocalizationServices mDateLocalizationServices;
   }
   ```
4. **Editor view**, Views/EditorTemplates/Parts/Validity.cshtml

   ```
   @model EventPart

   <fieldset>
     <legend>@T("Event")</legend>

     <fieldset>
       <div class="editor-label">
         <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.StartDateTimeProxy)">@T(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StartDateTimeProxy).AsString())</label>
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDateTimeProxy) @* will render Orchard`s datetime editor, see Orchard.Resources/Views/EditorTemplates/DateTimeEditor *@
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDateTimeProxy)
       </div>
     </fieldset>
   </fieldset>
   ```